# JQuery Multiselect not saving correct sequence on submit in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using JQuery Multiselect (http://loudev.com/) in a form in Rails. Everything works great but the order in which data is selected from the multiselect is not being saved.

I am basically having the same issue as here: [jquery multiselect selected data order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243417/jquery-multiselect-selected-data-order)

I need to implement a similar solution in Rails and any help would be much appreciated

Here is the code

THE FORM(the multiselect happens in the collection_select)

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function (){
       $('#load_format_column_sequence').multiSelect({ keepOrder: true });
  });

= form_for [:operate,@biller,@load_format], :remote => true do |form| 
  = form.fieldset :legend => 'General' do
    = form.text :name
    = form.text :load_processor
    = form.text :processor_options
    = form.fields_for(@load_format) do |builder|
      = builder.label "Column Sequence"
      = collection_select(:load_format, :column_sequence, load_format_column_sequence_select, :last, :first,  {}, {:multiple => true})
    = form.checkbox :inactivate_removed_accounts
  = form.fieldset :legend => 'Schedule and Transfer' do
    - @load_format.build_file_transfer_format unless @load_format.file_transfer_format
    = render :partial => 'operate/file_transfer_formats/form', :locals => { :form => form, :file_transfer_format => @load_format.file_transfer_format, :parent => @load_format, :show_schedule => true  }
```

Array of Data

```
def load_format_column_sequence_select
    {
      'EXTERNAL KEY' => :external_key,
      'EXTERNAL CODE' => :external_code,
      'ACCOUNT TYPE' => :account_type,
      'PAYER NAME' => :payer_name,
      'ALTERNATE PAYER NAME' => :payer_alternate_name,
      'PAYMENT AMOUNT' => :payment_amount,
      'PAYOFF AMOUNT' => :payoff_amount,
      'ACTIVE' => :active,
      'ALTERNATE KEYS' => :alternate_keys,
      'BILL EXTERNAL KEY' => :bill_external_key,
      'BILL EXTERNAL CODE' => :bill_external_code,
      'BILL DUE AMOUNT' => :bill_due_amount,
      'BILL DISCOUNT AMOUNT' => :bill_discount_amount,
      'BILL ALTERNATE KEY' => :bill_alternate_key,
      'DETAIL EXTERNAL KEY' => :detail_external_key,
      'DETAIL AMOUNT' => :detail_amount,
      'DETAIL DESCRIPTION' => :detail_description,
      'GROUP NAME' => :group_name,
      'GROUP EXTERNAL KEY' => :group_external_key,
      'RECENT CHECK ABA' => :recent_check_aba,
      'RECENT CHECK ACCOUNT' => :recent_check_account,
      'RECENT CHECK NUMBER' => :recent_check_num,
      'RECENT CHECK AMOUNT' => :recent_check_amount,
      'PAYER FIRST NAME' => :payer_first_name,
      'PAYER LAST NAME' => :payer_last_name,
      'ACCOUNT DESCRIPTION' => :account_description,
      'HOLD REASON KEYS' => :hold_reason_keys,
      'ACCOUNT ADDRESS LINE 1' => :account_address_line_1,
      'ACCOUNT ADDRESS LINE 2' => :account_address_line_2,
      'ACCOUNT CITY' => :account_city,
      'ACCOUNT STATE' => :account_state,
      'ACCOUNT ZIP CODE' => :account_zip
    }
  end
```

In the model i have

```
serialize(:column_sequence, Array)
```

Comment: Can we see the params that are being posted and strong params on the controller? Checking to see if the correct data is getting passed through.

Comment: hey chris! how goes it?
The param being passed in for this is just the column_sequence

In the console it looks like this (with 2 items from the array selected):

lf.column_sequence => "---\n- ''\n- payer_name\n- account_type\n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update...

switched to jquery bsmselect, very similar

solution was to add an argument to the load_format_column_sequence_select method, passing in the current order (which is an array of strings), inside the method, check if its set, if not set it to an empty array. Then set an empty hash as the new order, iterate over the current order array of strings to reorder the original list to match the column order.(gotta give my co worker credit for this one).

```
def load_format_column_sequence_select(current_order)
    current_order ||= []
    original_order = {
      :external_key => 'EXTERNAL KEY',
      :external_code => 'EXTERNAL CODE',
      :account_type => 'ACCOUNT TYPE',
      .........



    }

    new_order = {}

    current_order.each do |column_key|
      column_key = column_key.to_sym
      if column_name = original_order.delete(column_key)
        new_order[column_key] = column_name
      end
    end
    new_order.merge(original_order)

  end
```

and in the form.... ( the @load_format.column_sequence being passed in is the array of strings being saved in the db)

```
 = form.fields_for(@load_format) do |builder|
        = builder.label "Column Sequence"
        = collection_select(:load_format, :column_sequence, load_format_column_sequence_select(@load_format.column_sequence), :first, :last,  {}, {:multiple => true})
```