# Jquery Select2.js Selected dropdown order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Have checked the below link i am also facing the same issue but i am using select2.js please let me know how can i get the multi value in the same order which i have selected from multiselected dropdown.

[jquery multiselect selected data order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243417/jquery-multiselect-selected-data-order)

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: @Phiter actually there is multiselect dropdown menu for which i have used select2.js library but i need the dropdown data in the same order which i have selected but i am getting the value as per the dropdown order for more details you can check the above link. please help

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Select2 issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106), in multi-select: selections do not appear in the order in which they were selected.

Below is a snippet using the workaround proposed in that issue by user [xelax90](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106#issuecomment-196262305):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#select").select2({
   width: "100%",
  });

  $("#select").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
    var elm = evt.params.data.element;
    $elm = $(elm);
    $t = $(this);
    $t.append($elm);
    $t.trigger('change.select2');
  });
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <select multiple="multiple" id="select">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: may you please help me with version 3.2 select2. this is working perfect for 4.0 select2 version – Amit 21 mins ago

Comment: it should be indicated the version in the question, in particular if it is not the current version